Using find with regular expression
I try to understand how to use the find command with regular expressions (macOS 14.4.1, Zsh 5.9).
I have a directory with files such as note-red.png, note-yellow.png, (and other colors), folder-red.png, folder-yellow.png, (and other colors), but the following commands don't show any results when executed in that folder. What I'm doing wrong?
find -E . -regex '^(note|folder)'

find -E . -regex '^(note|folder).+'


The structure of the RE isn't correct. See man find on your Mac for details, which writes:

-regex pattern True if the whole path of the file matches pattern using regular expression. To match a file named ./foo/xyzzy, you can use the regular expression .*/[xyz]* or .*/foo/.*, but not xyzzy or /foo/.

So you would need to use -regex '.*/(note|folder)-.*'.
You've already noted the requirement to use -E that enables ERE alternation (and where the grouping syntax changes from \(...\) to (...)), so that's good:
find -E . -regex '.*/(note|folder)-.*'

Or for a more precise match (not matching intermediate directory names that happen to start with note- or folder-),
find -E . -regex '.*/(note|folder)-[^/]*\.png$'

You could also use the standard -name test to match the two patterns:
find . \( -name 'note-*.png' -o -name 'folder-*.png' \)

Or since you're using zsh, use its recursive globs instead of find:
print -rC1 -- **/(note|folder)-*.png(ND)

(also avoids the ./ prefix on the path and gets you a sorted list (which you can avoid with the oN qualifier) and makes it easier to script hidden files (by removing the D qualifier), though is likely to be slower).
